# List month number between two dates using c#

Tags: c#, date

I have two date

```
Start Date    End Date
02/25/2017    02/25/2018
```

I would like to list all the months and year falling between these dates. Any hint and help please

I want the final result as following:

```
Month Year
2     2017
3     2017
4     2017
5     2017
6     2017
7     2017
8     2017
9     2017
10    2017
11    2017
12    2017
1     2018
2     2018
```

Comment: Please show the code you have and where you think the logic is not correct.

Comment: Think about how you would do it manually... how would you do it with a calendar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following Logic,

```
DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(2017, 2, 25);
DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(2018, 2, 25);

while (dt1 < dt2)
{
    Console.WriteLine(dt1.ToString("MM-yyyy"));
    dt1 = dt1.AddMonths(1);
}
```

**[`DOTNETFIDDLE DEMO`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XWvHbo)**

Comment: Thank you; I also want to store each month to another variable. I have written the code but it is not working.               int[] months = new int[4;
                int i = 0;

                while (StartDate < EndDate)
                {
                    months[i] = StartDate.Month;
                    i += 1;
                }